# If statements containing and AND followed by an OR operator

Tags: php

I am attempting to ask:

- If my variable `$a` is set
- And if my variable `$a` is not `apple` or `orange`
- Then do something

I'm attempting to do this with the following code, but `true` is returned.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```php
<?php

    $a = 'banana';

    if (isset($a) && ($a !== 'apple' | $a !== 'orange')) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
```

Comment: It's `||` not `|`.

Comment: @0stone0 it still returns 'true'

Comment: `true` is expected since `$a` exists and it's not apple or orange

Comment: Your expression `$a !== 'apple' || $a !== 'orange'` will always evaluate as true since it will always be not equal to one or the other. If you don't want it to be equal to either, use `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `&&` instead off `||` (not `|`):

> And if my variable `$a` is not `apple` or `orange`

So if you don't want it to be either of those values, you'll need

```
($a !== 'apple' && $a !== 'orange')
```

So the script becomes

```php
<?php

    $a = 'banana';

    if (isset($a) && $a !== 'apple' && $a !== 'orange') {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
```

Now, `false` is shown if:

- `$a` is not set
- `$a` === `apple`
- `$a` === `orange`

---

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBDkBQDET3PcVIRDkD4iwl5UuExmclzv7VjpndvJexYCk1nQUjygUtuJfVyzXRPKKcY9SjzKVCUcCFrHVFzBbl77Ltsk7KFS6CR4ewgY/9VP@5oUvUHxnFlxel9AA)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `|` in your `or` expression

```
if (isset($a) && ($a !== 'apple' || $a !== 'orange')) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a | OR operation is ||

```
if (isset($a) && ($a !== 'apple' || $a !== 'orange')) {
```

Comment: It still returns 'true' with `||`

Comment: This is the expected result

Comment: If you want it to be false try using !($a === 'apple' || $a === 'orange')